# Non-differentiable regression penalties having non-zero probability of inducing sparsity

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

I was wondering if anyone has any analytic insight into *why* non-differentiable penalties can set coefficients to zero, and if there is a more relaxed alternative to this definition regarding the smoothness?

The usual explanation of a RSS level curve plot and a statement of selecting that one point to be probability zero leaves a lot to be desired here from the usual texts.